# How to catch input after enter in VUE?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Basically what I need is to call `find` method each time value changes.I cant use `watch` option of VUE as I need to call same function for lot of models.

`KeyPress` or `KeyDown` works almost fine except that it return the value without last char. For example if you enter `123` the `text` in `find` function will be `12`

```
<input type="text" v-model="name" v-on:keypress="find(name)">
<input type="text" v-model="name" v-on:keyDown="find(name)">


methods: {
    find: function(text) {
        console.log(text, this.name)
    }
}
```

Comment: `keypress`/`keydown` doesn't return the last char, so use `keyup`. The best event to listen for, though, is probably `input` - `keyup` will get fired for non-outputting keys (like `shift`)

Comment: use the `input` event if you want to run the function on every keystroke; use `change` if you want to run it when the user confirms they're done changing the value (which depends on the input type; for "text" inputs it would be on field blur.)

Answer (score 0):

You can extract key value from keyboard event which is passed to function. Following is fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/brijkishor/bokcrzwt/6/

```
JS:
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Input key press',
    name: ''
  },
  methods: {
    find: function(keyEvent) {
      console.log("key entered: ", keyEvent.key, ' : name: ', this.name);
    }
  }
})
// HTML
<div id="app">
  <input type="text" v-model="name" v-on:keydown="find">
  name: {{name}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved, have a look here https://jsfiddle.net/0phLz311/6/ don't forget to open DevTools console to see the expected behaviour of the method `find`.